# Post in REST API design

Tags: http, rest, api-design

I've been under the impression that Post in Rest means "Create".
But after reading up on the spec http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5

It seems like it can be more than just Create?
That was also stated by Stormpath in their screencasts on rest api design.

According to Stormpath, Post means "Process" , which can be pretty much anything.
Is that the correct way to see it?

I can trigger custom actions for my resources using Post?

Comment: When designing a RESTful service first think about your Resources. What are they? Then think about what happens to them: how are they created? By whom? With what data? Who can change them later? With what data? Only then will you be able to select the proper HTTP verb.

Comment: This is not about what verb to use, the question is about what I'm allowed to do using Post according to the spec. can I do other things than just "create" using "Post"

Comment: Just remember that `POST` is not save and not idempotent. As the client you must not expect that a repeated identical `POST` will have an identical result. If the action a `POST` request causes can handle this, you are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, a POST request should attempt to create or modify some resource on the server. As @Tichodroma pointed out, an idempotent request will affect this change only the first time it is sent, but otherwise what's important is that **some state on the server will be changed** by the request.

More practically. POST requests are often used when the request payload is **too large to fit into a GET URI** (e.g. a large file upload). This is usually an intentional breach of HTTP standards to avoid a `414 Request-URI Too Long` response.

In terms of verbiage, I don't know if I like "process", because even a GET request will usually be "processed" to determine the resource to return. The main difference in my mind is the change of some state on the server.